# Network Hyper V host with Virtual Machine

Tags: windows, hyper-v, windows-server-2012

Forgive me if this has been asked or is very rudimentary but I am just starting out and need to get this configured. I have been looking around and can't seem to find an answer.

I have a host server running Windows Server 2012 with a Hyper V Virtual Machine running on it. I need to get it set so that the host machine can access the vm. This has to be done without being connected to an external network.

We have a web site running on the host machine that needs to access some things on the vm.

Again I am new so step by step would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is pretty rudimentary, yes.

Basically, what you want to do is setup an internal network.

1. Create a new virtual network.

   - Hyper-V -> Virtual Network Settings.  Create a new internal network, and name it.  This will create a new virtual network adapter on the host machine.
2. Configure the host for the virtual network.

   - Go to the new network adapter for this internal network and set the network settings appropriately.
3. Add a new NIC on the virtual network to the guest VM

   - Modify the VM settings and add a NIC on the network you just set up in the guest.
4. Configure the new NIC on the guest.

   - Go to the new network adapter for this internal network and set the network settings appropriately.

Comment: Thanks for this. I know it is pretty basic, but I am just learning how to get these set up.

Comment: @AndyJ  No problem.  We all had to learn the basics at some point.